# How to create environment variable config files for django with virtualenv?

Tags: django, environment-variables

I am writing an automation script to intialize django projects depends on a list of questions answered by the user from console.

Answers will be put into environment variables, such as SERVER_ENVIRONMENT is either 'development' or 'production'

The problem I am facing is the environment variables don't `stick` by using `os.environ['var']`, which means next time I run the project, those variables are not there, so I need to persist those variables somewhere on the disk inside the project.

What's the best strategy to do so? Ideally it should be automatic, works both by `runserver` command and uwsgi processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you instead generate file and import it from the settings.py.

e.g. in settings.py put

```
import env_config
```

Where env_config.py will be generated by your script, will not be version-controlled and will have all the os.environ definitions (or just plain global variables?)

Comment: That's a plan, there is also a plan to add the entries to postactivate and postdeactivate